# Appcode and AppData not working in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created empty web Application on .net (Not Website).So I add Admin folder and under this i have added two folders , APPCode and AppData. When I am giving reference of AppData in Appcode it is not working.
I have class test.cs in AppCode and DAL.cs in AppData and i want to access DAL class in test. Here what I am using
System MyProject.Admin.AppData , One thing is that after Syatem .net not showing any inyellisence and all the above i coded myself.plz help me what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio - if you right click a file in App_Code and select properties, you need to select Build Action and set it to Compile. That will activate the intellisense for those classes.

This happens to me a lot...

Comment: Right click the project and add a reference to System.Net in there too - this happens to me with System.Configuration too.